# UISearchBar selecting Bug, Very Odd Bug

Tags: ios, searchbar

I have a tableview controller embedded in a navigation controller. Just below the navigation bar, I have a UISearchBar.
When I search, the "searchTableView pops up, and I can select the cell I want. But if after I select, while the search bar is animating dismissial, I select the grayish area where the search bar is disappearing, the navigation bar and search bar dissapear completely, leavin gjust white where they were.

Here is the code I call when a cell is selected:

```
if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchTableView]) {
    UITableViewCell * cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.usernameBeingDisplayed=cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    NUM_TO_DISPLAY=ORIGINAL_NUM_SHOWN;
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self refresh];
}
```

Comment: here's video I made showing the problem. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jffkhmeFYG4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I put together a hackey answer in the meantime. When the didendediting is called for the searchbar, I disable user interaction with the application for .25 seconds while the searchbar dismisses. Very hackey.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hackey answer occasionally still fails.